# Why is this for loop looping infinitely?

Tags: javascript, for-loop, scope

```
let n = 5;

for (let a = 1, b = Math.pow(2, a); b <= n; a++) {
   console.log(b);
}
```

I don't understand why `b` doesn't increase as `a` increases. Do I have to somehow pass `a` to `b` again?

If there's no way to make this loop work this way, can someone tell me how I could rewrite it so it works?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once `b` is initialized, your code never changes it, so the loop condition is always true.

You could use

```js
let n = 5;

for (b = 2; b <= n; b*=2) {
   console.log(b);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

b is of value type not of reference type. So updating a will not automatically update value of b

You have to update it manually

```
for (let a = 1,b =Math.pow(2,a); b <= n; a++,b=Math.pow(2,a)) {
   console.log(a);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you do have to pass `a` to `b` again in order to get your code to work, as `b` does not change as the loop progresses. Here is how you would rewrite your code to give it the functionality you want:

```
let n = 5;
let b;
for (let a = 1; b <= n; a++) {
   b = Math.pow(2, a);
   console.log(b);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get it working like below.
Your case is more likely fit for `while` or `do while` loop.

```js
let n = 5;
let a = 1;
   
while(powToA(a)<=n) {
   console.log(powToA(a));
   a++;
}


function powToA(a) {
  return Math.pow(2, a);
}
```